# Saleforce plug-in error in google cloud data fusion

Tags: salesforce, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm testing salesforce connectivity from Google Cloud Data Fusion. I get this error

> "Error: No discoverable found for request POST /v3/namespaces/system/apps/pipeline/services/studio/methods/v1/contexts/default/validations/stage HTTP/1.1"

when clicking on the get schema button in the connector.  Authentication details are all correct, I have tested it outside using Postman.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question

Answer (score 2):

Can you go to the System Admin link at the top right hand corner and check the status for Pipeline Studio? If it's red, can you click on the View Logs and see if there are any errors?

Comment: I've run into this same issue. In my case, the pipeline studio service is marked as down. I don't have any obvious errors in my logs either.

2020-04-08 21:31:43,440 - INFO  [program.status:i.c.c.i.a.r.d.DistributedProgramRunner@489] - Starting Service Program 'studio' with Arguments [logical.start.time=1586381495720, system.profile.name=SYSTEM:dataproc]
2020-04-08 21:42:35,937 - DEBUG [provisioning-service-1:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@121] - Executing DEPROVISION subtask REQUESTING_DELETE for program run program_run:system.pipeline.-SNAPSHOT.service.studio.