# GCP Data Fusion no discoverable foud error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I'm trying to use GCP Data Fusion Basic Edition with Private IP option, buth when I try to create a pipeline every action gives me this error

> No discoverable found for request POST /v3/namespaces/system/apps/pipeline/services/studio/methods/v1/contexts/default/validations/stage HTTP/1.1

any suggestion on how to solve this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is indicative of Pipeline Studio service being down. Check the status of Pipeline Studio in System Admin and look at the logs as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213119/saleforce-plug-in-error-in-google-cloud-data-fusion7213119/saleforce-plug-in-error-in-google-cloud-data-fusion).

You can restart the pipeline studio service by going to System Admin > Configuration > Make HTTP Call.

Change the method to `POST` and set path to `namespaces/system/apps/pipeline/services/studio/start`

You can validate your pipeline once pipeline studio status becomes green.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to restart the instance